# JQuery Selectors for siblings/children/parent

Tags: jquery, dom

So I feel like my title is almost ambiguous but the truth is I'm not even sure how to clarify...hence the question.

Html

```
<tr>  
  <div class="thisis(this)inmyexample"></div>
  <div class="stuff">
    <div class="foo"></div>
  </div>
</tr>
```

My question is on the difference in selectors.  Let's assume that `.stuff` is a sibling of `$(this)`  If I use this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.stuff .foo')
```

Now, I realize this isn't efficient coding but it's just as an easy example.  With it, I will find all classes of `.foo` that are children of `.stuff`.

If I use this:

```
$(this).siblings('.stuff .foo')
```

I won't find anything.  This is my inexperience with jquery talking, probably, but why wouldn't that kind of selector (what do you call a selector that uses a space or has both together, like `'.stuff.foo'`?) work with something like .siblings?  My expectation is that it would find all siblings with the class of `.stuff` and then find all children of `.stuff` with a class of `.foo`.  Is it not working because siblings/children/parent is looking for just the sibling/parent/child and won't look past that?

I know I can use this:

```
$(this).siblings('.stuff').children('.foo')
```

and I achieve my goal.  I'm just curious why my above selector (if that's what it's properly called) wouldn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PranavRam So it is because '.stuff foo' will never be a sibling of anything, right?

Comment: This is invalid HTML markup

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't feel that the html is really crucial to the question, besides knowing that `.stuff` and `$(this)` are siblings and `.foo` is  a child of `.stuff`.  Am I incorrect?

Comment: `siblings()` searches through all the siblings, seeing if they match the selector given, and none of the siblings will match `.stuff .foo`, it's really just that simple, and as an example try `siblings('.stuff:has(.foo)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you answered your own question, you won't find anything with $(this).siblings('.stuff .foo') because .foo is not a sibling of $(this), it's sort of a 'grandchild'.using that selector, it will look for .foo siblings that have .stuff parents, whereas you have $(this), a sibling of .stuff and .foo, a child of .stuff, and NOT a sibling of $(this).

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  Thanks!